# How to get the jquery value in php session in the same page

Tags: php, jquery, count

I'm trying to get the each jquery count value in php session on the same page but I am failed, please guide me what should I do.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var counter = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        count++;
        return count;
    };
})();

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#counter').text(counter());
    Counter=$("#counter").val();
});

});
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me!" />
<div id="counter">0</div>

<?php
echo $_SESSION['Counter'];
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an AJAX call for that. Consider this example:

First bind your button to make an ajax call, every click, request to server to start the increment.

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me!" />
<div id="counter"><?php echo (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) ? $_SESSION['counter'] : 0; ?></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data: {counter: true},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#counter').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Then server then sets the counter to the session.

```
<?php

// initial setting
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

// for every click increment the counter
if(isset($_POST['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
    echo json_encode($_SESSION['counter']);
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @kevinabelita for reply, its really working great as i wish, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly assign JavaScript variable to php because [PHP is server side scripting lagauge](http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/a/Php-Is-A-Server-Side-Language.htm) and [JavaScript client side](http://www.w3schools.com/web/web_javascript.asp). You have to use [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) send counter to a function and save it to session, in response you will get stored session  value.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Rorschach but i don't know how to use ajax to pass the value form get or post so can you help me, can you post that sample code here?